# Cycle template tag only works with fixed number of arguments

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm using the template tag [cycle](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle) to add different css classes to an element dependent on the index of a loop in a Django template. See following example:

```
{% for id in menus %}
    <div class="col-md-2 {% cycle 'col-md-offset-1' %}">
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

This throws an `No named cycles in template. ''col-md-offset-1'' is not defined` Error.

The `menus`list has 5 entries and if I adjust the number of arguments for the `cycle` method to the number of list entries it works:

```
{% for id in menus %}
    <div class="col-md-2 {% cycle 'col-md-offset-1' '' '' '' ''%}">
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Does the cycle template tag always needs to have the exact number of arguments as the used list? This sounds wrong to me.

Is there a different way to set a class only for the first element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you're trying to use cycle for only one thing. That doesn't make sense.

If you want to set a class for the first element only, use `{% if forloop.first %}`.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed. I guess I overcomplicated it. I also realized that you need at least two arguments for the cylce tag to work properly.